# Using string array in sqlclient commandtext

Tags: c#, sqlcommand, sqlclient

Here is the code I have so far. `comm` is a string array, `ds` is a dataset type variable.

```
comm = new string[flist.Count()];

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

for (int i = 0; i <= flist.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    comm[i] = "select tblcustodians.name as Custodian,count(*) as Nondupe, dupstatus from tbldoc join tblcustodians on tbldoc.custodianid = tblcustodians.id where path like '" + flist[i] + "%' group by tblcustodians.name, dupstatus order by custodian ASC";

    mycomm.CommandText = comm[i];

    adapter.SelectCommand = mycomm;

    adapter.Fill(ds);
}
```

I am trying to build a loop, so the `CommandText` will change with the loop, and eventually the dataset will be filled with datatables generated by each comm array, but this code only gives me a dataset with 1 datatable which is queried by `comm[0]`.

Can anyone help me to sort this thing out, and tell me what is wrong? Thanks

Comment: Warning: the string concatenation technique you are using to build your queries is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. This is a _very serious problem_. Please read up on how to use parameterized queries right away.

Comment: Thanks Joel. I am studying what you suggest now.